# Modify raster coordinates (wrong projection) using stars or terra

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, terra, stars

I downloaded a raster image from the following address, which corresponds to rivers and streams in the Barcelona area.

https://geoserveis.icgc.cat/icgc_geotecnicbcn25m/wms/service?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=RIER_LN&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/tiff&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:25831&BBOX=415134.5624,4571467.0516,444192.4298,4589092.5720&WIDTH=1634&HEIGHT=990

However, the coordinates are absolutely wrong, as the bbox has turned into (0,0,17,10.3125) instead of the (415134.5624,4571467.0516,444192.4298,4589092.5720) I was looking for. When making a quick plot with tmap, it appears correct (not deformed), exactly the same map than here.
[image: target image]

Hence, is there any way I can change the coordinates, even if it is by simple direct proportionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why the extent and CRS are both horribly wrong in the TIFF.

You can set the extent and coordinate system manually

```
> r = rast("download.tiff")
> crs(r) = "epsg:25831"
> ext(r) = c(415134.5624,4571467.0516,444192.4298,4589092.5720)[c(1,3,2,4)]
```

Note how I have pasted the extent from the request URL but have rearranged it using a subset vector because its not in the right order for the `ext` function.

Now, in theory you should be able to run tmap on that and get it. But:

```
> tm_shape(r) + tm_rgb()
stars object downsampled to 1284 by 778 cells. See tm_shape manual (argument raster.downsample)
Error in CPL_transform(x, crs, aoi, pipeline, reverse, desired_accuracy,  : 
  OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(): transformation not available
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_transform(x, crs, aoi, pipeline, reverse, desired_accuracy,  :
  GDAL Error 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `ENGCRS["unnamed",EDATUM[""],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]' to `EPSG:4326'
>
```

Something in `tmap` is not happy with trying to transform to lat-long. Possible `stars`? If we try using `rast`'s reprojection to lat-long so that `tmap` doesn't have to:

```
> rp = project(r, "epsg:4326")                                         
> tm_shape(rp) + tm_rgb()
```

then we get:

[image]

which is definitely over Barcelona... The lines do seem to line up with some features on the ground - usually roads though... maybe this is drainage of some sort... Anyway... If I load into QGIS and use "multiply" blend to see through the white...

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. You're not supposed to see them because they run through the sewers, but here's where they are supposed to be.